# How to have different content type in ngRepeat depending on some condition?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

For my problem I am trying to create a list out of data received from server. From this list only 5 top items should be shown by default and if the list `items["instance"]` has more than 5 items it should show a `more` button & on click of this button it should display the rest of the items for that accordion content.

Below is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="MainCtrl" id="bpNaminConvention">

                <accordion>
                    <accordion-group is-open="item.open" ng-repeat="item in namingConventions">
                        <accordion-heading style="margin-left: 0px">
                            <span class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-class="{'down-accordion': item.open, 'up-accordion': !item.open}" style="margin-right: 10px"></span>
                            <label class="filter-headItem">
                                <!-- <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-click="filterHeaderClick(item.title, $event)" ng-model="master" value="{{item.title}}" style="margin-top:1px; margin-right:5px" /> -->
                                {{ item.title }}
                            </label>
                            <span style="margin-left: 15px;padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; background-color: #FFCC4E">{{item.itemCount}}</span>
                        </accordion-heading>
                        <div>
                            <table style="margin-left: 12px">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="filter-headItem">{{item.title}} should be named as </label><b> {{ item.contentText }}</b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="filter-subItem">
                                                Example.
                                                <p>
                                                    <span ng-repeat="data in item.exampleText">
                                                    {{data}}<br/> 
                                                </span>
                                                </p>
                                                <br/> {{item.itemCount}} instance located for improper naming.
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label id="namingConventionInstances" class="filter-headItem">
                                                <ul ng-repeat="instance in item.filterItems" ng-show="item.filterEnabled" ng-switch="$last">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span ng-switch-default>{{instance}}<br/></span>
                                                        <a class="namingConventionMoreATag" ng-click="showAllNamingConventionItems(item.title)" ng-switch-when="true">{{instance}}</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <ul ng-repeat="instance in item.instance" ng-hide="item.filterEnabled">
                                                    <li><span>{{instance}}</span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>

</div>

$scope.init = function() {
    var result = [{"title":"Agents","contentText":"<Agents>","exampleText":["For Windows: Marketing","For Linux: Automation"],"itemCount":6,"open":true,"filterItems":["FIB","JAQULIN","NOMNOM","JAGERY","MINC","more"],"filterEnabled":true,"instance":["FIB","JAQULIN","NOMNOM","JAGERY","MINC","WIN2008-64","more"]},{"title":"Task","contentText":"<Connection>","exampleText":["DC_Oracle_Contact_INS","DC_Oracle_Contact_UPD","DC_Oracle_Contact_DEL","DC_Oracle_Contact_UPSERT"],"itemCount":10,"open":false,"filterItems":["C_FIB","C_TEST","C_TEST_2","DB1","DB1_2","more"],"filterEnabled":true,"instance":["C_FIB","C_TEST","C_TEST_2","DB1","DB1_2","DC1","DC2 FIB","DB to DB SM","DB to DB FIB","DR1_som","more"]},{"title":"Task Flow","contentText":"<Source Type>_<Target Type>_<Operation Type>","exampleText":["DC_Oracle _INS","DC_Oracle _UPD","DC_Oracle _DEL","DC_Oracle _UPSERT"],"itemCount":1,"open":false,"filterItems":["Task flow1"],"filterEnabled":false,"instance":["Task flow1"]},{"title":"Scheduler","contentText":"Schedule_<Frequency>","exampleText":["Schedule_Five_Minutes","Schedule_Hourly","Schedule_Daily"],"itemCount":5,"open":false,"filterItems":["daily","every 45 min","s2","test","testing"],"filterEnabled":false,"instance":["daily","every 45 min","s2","test","testing"]}];
    $scope.renderNamingConventionAccord(result);

  }
$scope.showAllNamingConventionItems = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }

  $scope.renderNamingConventionAccord = function(result) {
    $scope.namingConventions = result;
  }

  $scope.init();
```

Below is a screenshot of my accordion

![enter image description here][1]

Here is a **updated** [unfinished plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/rNI6xkgP5vo0WBVFQo1X?p=preview)

To summarize I need solution for 2 below problems

1. If list item is more than 5 it should display `more` which is clickable to show the rest of the items.
2. The `more` button should not have `li` bullet.

**Update**

Adding more description on why I am using `getBestPracticesNamingConventionData` function (check [plunker link "helper.js"](http://plnkr.co/edit/rNI6xkgP5vo0WBVFQo1X?p=preview))

I am preparing Server side data `result` in `getBestPracticesNamingConventionData` function to be used by accordion. Essentially below items are needed

```
items["title"] //title of accordion
items["contentText"] //some text
items["exampleText"] //some more text
items["itemCount"] //*this count should be used to check >5 and truncate extra items and display only when more button is clicked
items["open"] //to trigger accordion open 
items["instance"] //*this is the item list which needs to be truncated and shown accordingly as stated above.
```

So basically I need help with * above items, on how it can be used in accordion.

**Update**

As requested by [NewDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968155/new-dev) I have prepared a plunker with bare minimum stuff.

Comment: Can you remove all the irrelevant code and show just the minimum needed for your problem. You have enough SO reputation to know that the intent is for the questions to be reusable for future viewers, not to mention that it shows that you care about helping those who would help you.

Comment: @NewDev: I have removed irrelevant code as much as possible.

Comment: Really? Is it necessary to have all the elaborate markup with styles for this question? Is `getBestPracticesNamingConventionData` really fundamental to this issue? Ultimately, it's up to you how you want to phrase your question.

Comment: @NewDev: `getBestPracticesNamingConventionData` is used to prepare data (fetched from elasticsearch response) for the accordion. I am trying to show my approach on how I am preparing the data which will be given to the accordion, So that if any one has better idea, they can modify the data itself for their approach.

Comment: @NewDev: I have added some more explanation on how I am preparing data, and what is essential in the formatted data.

Comment: I've given you my feedback - you need to remove all of your business logic and domain-specific stuff, and prepare a rudimentary sample (and simple) app that still showcases your problem. No need to see your actual data or data pre-processing or styling or markup.

Comment: you said "The more button should not have li bullet." but i see you have bullet in your code. Do you want to remove it (i.e. put the more after ul)?

Comment: @Aidin: Yes, I need more button not to have li bullet.

Comment: @NewDev: Thank you for taking interest. I have prepared a [plunker with bare minimum stuff](http://plnkr.co/edit/x9w5mtrqAuQDOQHvZVLj?p=preview) will update my question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for simplifying the code in your problem.

To solve this, you need the following:

First, you'd need to define a local (to the current iteration of `accordion`'s `ng-repeat`) variable to change the number of items you want to display. One way is define it in the controller, but in this case it would be better to use `ng-init`. This needs to be done on any ancestor element of the `item.instance`'s `ng-repeat`, for example on a `<td>`:

```
<td ng-init="limit = 5">
```

Then, to actually limit the number of `ng-repeat` results, you can use the `limitTo` filter. It would be helpful to alias the filtered list - this only works in Angular 1.3. So, together this would be:

```
<td  ng-init="limit = 5">
  <ul ng-repeat="instance in item.instance | limitTo: limit as shownInstances">
    <li>{{instance}</li>
  </ul>
</td>
```

Lastly, you'd need a "show more" button. This is where `shownInstances` alias is useful, because you'd only want to show the button if the number of shownInstances is less than the total number:

```
<button ng-show="shownInstances.length < item.instance.length"
        ng-click="limit = limit + 5">
   show more
</button>
```

Here's your updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ThhBL8lz5gWpnzuJo4pv?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your time in solving my problem, even i was able to solve my problem, got some help from [here](https://gist.github.com/fraserxu/e965101a4b26d8d41e58/download#). I am pretty new to angularjs so did not knew about [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo). Your solution is more generic so I am marking your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/rNI6xkgP5vo0WBVFQo1X?p=preview). Got some help from [here](https://gist.github.com/fraserxu/e965101a4b26d8d41e58). Now using [limitTo directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) to limit list item Thank you all.

```
<label class="filter-headItem" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="instance in item.instance | limitTo:item.limit">
            <span>{{instance}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href ng-click="item.limit = item.instance.length; item.filterEnabled = false" ng-show="item.filterEnabled">more</a>
</label>
```

I am changing the way I am preparing my data. Adding limit to it and changing it whenever needed and hiding more button

```
for(i=0; i<bp_titles.length; i++) {
    var items = {}, maxFilterItems = 5, tempContentArray = [], tempActArray = [], more = "more";        
    items["title"] = bp_titles[i];
    items["contentText"] = bp_contentText[i];
    items["exampleText"] = bp_exampleText[i];
    items["itemCount"] = contentArray[i].length;
    items["limit"] = maxFilterItems;

    if (i==0) {
        items["open"] = true;
    }
    else
        items["open"] = false;

    if (contentArray[i].length > maxFilterItems) {
        items["filterEnabled"] = true;
    }
    else {
        items["filterEnabled"] = false;
    }
    items["instance"] = contentArray[i];
    if (contentArray[i].length != 0) {
        mainArray.push(items);
    }        
}
```

Comment: You don't need to change your underlying data - see my answer.